# How to save tensorflow hub model for serving in tensorflow model serving

Tags: tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-hub

I want to use tensorflow object detection model from tensorflow hub for hosting in model serving.
I am able to download model but not able to save in model serving format.
Any one have idea ?

Answer (score 4):

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

detector = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2")
tf.saved_model.save(detector, 'objmodel')
```